# Facebook cookie retained until manual referesh

Tags: session, cookies, redirect, facebook

I'm building a PHP site that uses Facebook OAuth as the login mechanism. The problem is that when the user logs out and is directed back to my site, the site is still effectively logged (at least in appearance) in until the user manually refreshes the page.

I suspect the reason for this is because the Facebook cookies are removed only once the return page has finished rendering. I accept I'm not fully versed in the way sessions work.

User logs out
  -> Redirect to Facebook
    -> Redirect back to site (logout.php)
    -> Clear local session
      -> Redirect to home page (index.php)
      -> Page renders (still logged in)
      -> Cookies removed
        -> Manual refresh (index.php)
        -> Page renders (no longer logged in).

I had a similar issue with an ASP.NET MVC site a little while ago. My fix then was to parse the page with JavaScript after the page had loaded and once the cookies had finally been removed.

I am working on the assumption that I'm doing something wrong. I simply want index.php to recognise that Facebook is logged out without having to refresh.

I use `header()` to redirect from logout.php to index.php.

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

EDIT:
I have tried appending the current time to the redirect url in order to side step caching problems. This has not helped.

EDIT:
Watching cookie activity in FireCookie backs up my suspision that the Auth cookie is removed after the page is rendered. This is obviously not conclusive as FireCookie doesn't show me what's happening server side.

JS Workaround:
My current workaround is to run the following snippet on page load, where $fbUid is the Facebook User ID. It's not ideal though, because it relies on JavaScript.

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (<?php echo $fbUid ? "true" : "false" ?> && response.session == null)
                window.location.reload();
        });
```

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it with help from [Delete facebook session cookie from my application on users logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265844/delete-facebook-session-cookie-from-my-application-on-users-logout/4776187#4776187) and the SDK source.

Adding this code snippet to the logout page ensures that the authentication is properly removed.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FB_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$fbCookieName = 'fbs_' . $facebook->getAppId();

$domain = $facebook->getBaseDomain();
if ($domain) {
  $domain = '.' . $domain;
}

setcookie($fbCookieName, '', time() - 3600, '/', $domain);
$facebook->setSession();
```

The code empties the cookie and expires it at the same time. The session is then explicitly removed.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Probably a cacheing issue. Add some randomly generated value to the query string in the redirect, so it'll appear as a "new" page to the browser, something like:

```
header('Location: index.php?cachebuster=' . microtime(true));
```

That should force the browser to fetch a fresh copy, which would then not have the "logged in" content anymore.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks for the input, but it didn't work. I truly think the cookie actually remains until the page has been passed to the browser.

Comment: Then use Firebug and/or HTTPFox to view the headers for the requests. You'll be able to see exactly when the cookie appears and disappears.

Comment: @Marc B This is what has led me to believe that the cookies are only removed after the page has rendered.

Comment: Shouldn't be. Cookies are send via the request headers, which are sent before any of the actual page contents

Comment: @Marc B Which makes sense, but then how does my JS workaround work? The Facebook user I'd should be no longer accessible on the server.

Comment: Perhaps adding some no-cache headers to your index page if it's loaded via the facebook logout redirect. I don't know... have your script log the $_COOKIE array for each request while all this is going on and see what's loaded when. And check the server's access_log to see what kind of hit was registered on the page. If the still-logged-in hit on index.php shows up as something other than a 200 OK (e.g. 302 if-modified-since), then it's a cacheing issue.

Answer (score 0):

hi i have same this issue but i resolve this issue 
buy using this 
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

window.location.reload();
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
window.location.reload();
});

please add this script where you have to write your login code. and enjoy