# logout problem with facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "";
$app_key = "";
$app_secret = "";
$canvas_url = "";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true,
'domain' => 'http://www.yeospace.com/2B10030/'
));


$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session) {

    try{
        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, user_photos, read_stream, read_friendlists, offline_access, manage_pages'
        ));

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e)
        {//catch
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);   
        }//catch
    }//end if session user 
else
{

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        //$updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));
        echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture'/>". "<br />" ;
        echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
        //echo "You last updated your profile on " . $updated  . "<br />" ;


}//end else user
```

I have this application which is having logout problem. The code above is a config.php where every other page will include. "require_once 'config.php'"
When i logout user A and login user B, then when i run the application again, the data in the application was still user A.

Is there anyway where i could force clear the data then load the new one? Even thought this config.php was always being load the user data was not cleared.
Could you guys advice me on how i could clear this. I am still unfamiliar with facebook application. THank you!

Comment: logout from facebook? does that counts as logout too?
I am having problems with my codes, the application will jump from facebook application into my server url instead of staying on facebook. It is because of my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you are not doing in any of this code:

1. [Destroying the Facebook session for the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265844/delete-facebook-session-cookie-from-my-application-on-users-logout/4776187#4776187)
2. [Destroying the PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

this is why you are preserving the state of the previous user even though you have switched users.

Comment: Thanks Wes for the tips. If i add session_destroy() will it do the trick? Sorry that i am noob to codings.

Comment: @meAtStackOverflow Updated the post with links for help

Answer (score 0):

On facebook doc, they suggest to use:

```
Facebook::getLogoutUrl( $params=array() )
```

This method returns a URL that, when clicked by the user, will log them out of their Facebook session and then redirect them back to your application.

You should use following code:

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'https://www.myapp.com/after_logout' );
$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

Check facebook sdk ref. doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/