# Can't change the user using facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook, logout

I developped an access PHP page using facebook connect (SDK for PHP).

But when I change the facebook account (change the user: logout from the first user facebook account and login to the second user), then my website login, using facebook connect, loads the first user info.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your cache after you log out of the first account.

You can also remove the cookies that Facebook left for your app.  [Look at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265844/delete-facebook-session-cookie-from-my-application-on-users-logout)

Comment: It works. Indeed, I have to clear the cache. But how to do it automatically? I mean how to do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The logout problem is because of a recent Facebook API change – ‘offline_access Permission Removal’.

Currently by default access_token returned by Facebook is long lived (60 days). So you cannot log out of the app by clicking the logout link. Even loging out of Facebook will not log the user out of your app.

To use the old setting disable the ‘Deprecate offline access’ setting from Edit App > Advanced > Migrations tab.

Comment: Ok, I disabled this setting. But it still doesn't work. How long do I have to wait until the user can change? Is it better to manually delete (or alter) the fb cookie?

Comment: Users can change instantly.. Are you asking for 'offline_access' permission?? If yes, please remove that permission and then try..

Comment: Ok. It finally works. I had to clear the cache after disabling the setting. Thanks for your help.